# Attempting to configure a user that get Configuration-Token in reply

Tags: freeradius

I have tried most of the configuration examples of user to return a Configuration-Token attribute. I need an example configuration and which file to place it in (e.g. user or user.conf).

tried something like (in user.conf):

testing Cleartext-Password := "password"
    reply: Configuration-Token="hello"

This caused freeradius to not run

Freeradius would not execute.

Comment: Figured out the syntax by trial and error:

Comment: herb User-Password == "mine"
  Reply-Message =* ANY,
  Tunnel-Type := VLAN,
  Tunnel-Medium-Type := IEEE-802,
  Tunnel-Private-Group-Id := "100",
  Configuration-Token := "token",
  Session-Timeout := "1000",
  Idle-Timeout := "500"